# No Cookies on event request for my svelte deployed application on contabo server

Tags: cookies, deployment, svelte, sveltekit, setcookie

I deployed my svelte app where  in hook.server.js i use jwt token stored in Cookies to verify if user is authenticated but my server there is not cookies in request Event. I mention that i don't have any issue in local.
Here is my login where i set token in cookies :

```
/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    logIn: async ({ cookies, request, locals }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const username = data.get('username');
        const password = data.get('password');
        const body = { username, password };
        const response = await login(body);
        const { user, accessToken } = response;
        locals.user = user;
        cookies.set('auth', accessToken, { path: '/', sameSite: 'lax' });
        locals.token = accessToken;
        console.log("testcook", cookies.get('auth'));
        throw redirect(303, '/');

    },
}
```

Here is my handle function in hook.server.js

```
export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    console.log("handle hook", event.cookies.get('auth'));
    const userToken = event.cookies.get('auth');
        /*i take token and call backend to verify validity of token*/
    const user = await authenticateUser(userToken);
    if (!user && event.url.pathname !== "/login") {
        console.log(event.locals.user);
        event.locals.user = null;
        console.log("redirecting to login")
        throw redirect(303, "/login")
    }
    event.locals.user = user;
    event.locals.token = await event.cookies.get('auth');
    return resolve(event);
}
```

After login in server-ip:port/login  with good data, my console log in login (console.log("testcook", cookies.get('auth'));) give good result and throw to "/" but  `console.log("handle hook", event.cookies.get('auth'));` in handle function of hook.server.js is alwayss undefined.
But in localhost i don't have issue.

I try to add domain but n
cookies.set('auth', accessToken, { path: '/', sameSite: 'lax' , domain:'ip'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to how you are setting the cookie. I had to play around the cookie options to get it to work. Try these options:

```
{
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true
}
```